# Accessing objects inside recursive NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

I have a problem with accessing objects inside NSDictionary.

The app downloads XML from a web server, and then parse it to NSDictionary with the XMLReader lib.. And now i don't know how to access the objects inside the NSDictionary.

my xml structure is:

```
<xml>
 <categories>
  <category id="1" name="test">
   <questions>
    <question id="1" category_id="1" question="boxes?"/>
    <question id="2" category_id="1" question="cash?"/>
   </questions>
  </category>
  <category id="2" name="blah">
   <questions>
    <question id="3" category_id="2" question="hara?"/>
   </questions>
  </category>
 </categories>
```

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost/DoNotForget/API/database.xml"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"database.xml"];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
[request startSynchronous];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *test = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:err];
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

how can i for example run with loop on the categories items, or for example access the question id 1 inside the category id 1?

Sorry for my bad english,
Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Any docs on how the library turns the XML into data structures?

Comment: Get familiar with the debugger and explore the dictionary in question.  Complete unsolicited advice follows:  ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under development.  The developer has encouraged other devs to find alternatives such as AFNetworking.  If this is a new app, and your willingness and ability to fix Core Foundation networking code is suspect, then an alternative is probably indicated.

Comment: You should post your log of test, that would be more helpful than the XML.

Answer (score 0):

something like that doesn't work?

1. Access the question

   MyQuestion *question = [[test objectForKey:@"1"] objectForKey:@"1"];

   2.For should work well

   for (NSString* key in test) {
           id value = [test objectForKey:key];
           // do work with Object or You could use code like 
           above to access property inside 
       }